# Live streaming doesn't work

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm using FFmpeg to capture my screen:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -r 5 -s 640x480 -acodec libmp3lame -ac 1 -vcodec mpeg 4 -vtag divx -q 10 -f mpegts tcp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

so let it stream to somewhere. The accepter script:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL); /* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
 set_time_limit(30); /* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting as it comes in. */
 ob_implicit_flush();


$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 1234;
$outfile = dirname(__FILE__)."/output.flv";
$ofp = fopen($outfile, 'wb');

 if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) { echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) { echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) { echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); die; }
 if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) { echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n"; sleep (5); break; }
 do {
    $a = '';
    socket_recv ($msgsock, $a, 65536, MSG_WAITALL);
    fwrite ($ofp, $a);
    //echo strlen($a)."\r\n";
 } while (true);
```

it seems to save the stuff to the disk OK. Now here comes the html:

I dont really know how to do this, but based on an example:

```
<video src="/output.flv"></video>
```

but it doesn't do anything. And if I want to stream the live incoming stuff, then what's the matter?

Comment: Which browser? Note that at the moment, different browsers support different codecs. Note also to set the correct MIME type via PHP, it has caused issues with FF for me.

Comment: its firefox, I havent tried it with other browsers. But its going to be a live stream (no start/finish), so mightbe it misses the file identifier headers? Perhaps it expects static format?

Comment: it doesnt work with any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML 5 Video will not support the Flv format HTML5 will be support the following format video only

```
.mp4 = H.264 + AAC
.ogg/.ogv = Theora + Vorbis
.webm = VP8 + Vorbis
```

study the HTML5 video basics in the following site 
[HTML5 video basics](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)

if you want to play the flv you have to use the flash or Flex program or some flv players like flowplayer